# Deserializing an array of name value pairs to an object using Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a JSON that looks like this,

```
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "msg": [
    "id",
    "123",
    "score",
    "15901862",
    "duration",
    "10"
  ]
}
```

*msg* is an array of strings with a *key name followed by its value*.

I need to deserialize it to a class structure of this form,

```java
class Result {

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;

    @JsonProperty("msg")
    private Message message;
}

class Message {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private long messageId;

    @JsonProperty("score")
    private long score;

    @JsonProperty("duration")
    private long duration;
}
```

I would like to still leverage the *JsonProperty* annotation to set the right property during deserialization. What's the most efficient way to do this in Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @JsonProperty("msg")
private Message message;
```

Phoenix's attribute should be an array.

Comment: dont`t phoenix  
message`s attribute should be an array

Comment: The array in the json needs to be mapped to an object.

Comment: The message attribute should be a List type or array, and the generic type should be a string.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have misunderstood what you mean.

Why not use hash?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Result {

@JsonProperty("status")
private String status;

@JsonProperty("msg")
private List<String> message;
}
```

like this

Comment: Please [provide some explanations along with your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), so that future users can follow your ideas/code more easily. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23894580)